# Making the jqueryUI theme picker widget work with localhost versions of css files

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, themes, jquery-ui-theme

The jQueryUI theme picker widget is awesome and I would really like to use it for a project in ASP.NET. But the theme picker loads the files from the jQuery website which isn't necessary because I have a copy of it. I did look into the code that is created by the theme switcher widget from here http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/themeswitchertool/ and the urls are hardcoded. Well I don't mind changing the url's :) just wondered why all those styles and font sizes have been specified in the query string and how can I get it to work with my local files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's dead simple. After looking into the theme switcher gadget i was able to understand that html markup for the themes too are hard coded. Here is a snippet of how your new to be added theme should look if you wanted to add custom themes.

```
<ul>
<li>
<a link="relative link to css">
<img src="source of image to show in drop down"/>
<span>Theme name</span>
</a>
<li>
</ul>
```

you just have to create a image of for how the theme looks in image editor, drop the link to css that's it.